# Can't update to Laravel 5.8 from 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.8

I am trying to upgrade my site from Laravel 5.7 to 5.8.

I changed `laravel/framework` in `composer.json` to "5.8.*" and then run `composer update` but the result from composer is this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/nexmo-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravel/slack-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: staudenmeir/dusk-updater
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-editor
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-html
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan ide-helper:generate
A new helper file was written to _ide_helper.php
> php artisan ide-helper:meta
A new meta file was written to .phpstorm.meta.php
```

I even tried updating the version number in the `composer.lock` but that didn't work either, it just reverted back the version to "5.7.28".

EDIT 1:

Tried also deleting `composer.lock` but got a similar result, here it is:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
    You can run './vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon' to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/nexmo-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravel/slack-notification-channel
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: staudenmeir/dusk-updater
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-editor
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-fractal
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-html
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle
Package manifest generated successfully.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postUpdate
> php artisan ide-helper:generate
A new helper file was written to _ide_helper.php
> php artisan ide-helper:meta
A new meta file was written to .phpstorm.meta.php
```

EDIT 2:

I did this:

```
composer require laravel/framework ^5.8
```

the result is:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.8.1
    - laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 requires illuminate/view 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28], illuminate/view[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 requires illuminate/view 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28], illuminate/view[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - laravelcollective/html v5.7.1 requires illuminate/view 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28], illuminate/view[5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.15, v5.7.2, v5.7.20, v5.7.21, v5.7.22, v5.7.23, v5.7.26, v5.7.27, v5.7.28, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.7.28].
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.7.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.7.18|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view 5.7.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.8.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^5.8 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.8.0, v5.8.1, v5.8.10, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.13, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.16, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.20, v5.8.21, v5.8.22, v5.8.23, v5.8.24, v5.8.3, v5.8.4, v5.8.5, v5.8.6, v5.8.7, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
    - Installation request for laravelcollective/html (locked at v5.7.1) -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.7.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried deleting composer.lock?

Comment: Just did, added result to my question.

Comment: "Nothing to install or update" means you're already up to date. Check `composer.lock` and see what version of Laravel it shows is installed. Or try `composer require laravel/framework ^5.8`.

Comment: composer.lock shows v5.7.28

Comment: tried `composer require laravel/framework ^5.8` see the result in my question

Comment: @ceejayoz any ideas?

Comment: @PetarVasilev Now we're getting somewhere. What does the `laravelcollective/html` line of your `composer.json` say?

Comment: Well it says this: `requires illuminate/view 5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.7.28]` but isn't Laravel 5.8 supposed to use newer version?

Comment: @PetarVasilev No, the line in `composer.json` that says `laravelcollective/html`. Chances are you've locked it to v5.7, and it thus can't be upgraded alongside Laravel.

Comment: Did you update Carbon? Is this an option for you? `./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon`

Comment: I don't even have `laravelcollective/html` as top level dependency, it must be dependency of something else.

Comment: @waterloomatt I don't want to upgrade to Carbon 2 right now

Comment: @PetarVasilev Well, figure out which of your dependencies need `laravelcollective/html`, and update that. (You can likely look in `composer.lock` for the package.) Something's telling Composer "I need `laravelcollective/html` v5.7.1" and that means Laravel 5.8 can't be installed as it conflicts.

Comment: Please can you add your `composer.json` file to your question.

Comment: could be an issue with laravelcollective/html try the following command `composer require laravelcollective/html:"5.8.*"`

Comment: Had to remove "yajra/laravel-datatables" and install it again that solved it.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this

```
composer require laravel/framework ^5.8 --update-with-dependencies
```

> --update-with-dependencies: Also update dependencies of the newly required packages, except those that are root requirements.

Or when updating a package

```
composer update laravel/framework --with-dependencies
```

> --with-dependencies: Add also dependencies of whitelisted packages to the whitelist, except those that are root requirements.

In other words this will update other packages besides `laravel/framework` which are required for the update to Laravel 5.8.

Comment: Please note that the name of the option when used with the `require` command is `--update-with-dependencies`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the `./vendor/bin/upgrade-carbon` as suggested in your error message? I recently encountered a similar issue with different framework, but after upgrading Carbon to v2 I could update my framework and other packages.